# Asp.Net Core Api 404 Not Found .Master

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a database where some of the strings contain .Master as part of their string. I have an API to access the strings(I have to access them by the string not another column), however I get the error:

HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.

I know that the issue is due to a configuration somewhere, however I'm not sure where that setting would be. I looked at other questions regarding a 404.7 error, but was unable to find a solution that worked for me. How can I allow the .Master at the end of a query string?

Answer (score 0):

When IIS receives a request it looks for a handler to respond to the request based on the path and extension. ASP.NET Web API is called by the TransferRequestHandler handler for url that doesn't have an extension.

So you need to change the IIS config to make this handler respond to request with any extension. Add in web.config :

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="MyWebAPIHandler" path="api/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This will adds a new handler to respond to requests for the path /api with every extension. This allows the staticFile handler to continue working for requests on other paths so static files like scripts or style are still accessible.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up figuring out is that you can go into the .vs/config/applicationhost.config.

Once you are inside there you find the < requestFiltering > xml tag. In there, there is a list of extensions that are allowed. You just have to find the extension you want to allow and and set its property to true.

```
<requestFiltering>
    <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true">
        <add fileExtension=".ascx" allowed="false" />
        <add fileExtension=".master" allowed="true" />
    </fileExtensions>
</requestFiltering>
```